# memory problems, collection view, coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, out-of-memory

so I have this problem here that when I pick more than a few images in the controller, my memory goes insane. as seen below I convert the images and store them in CoreData, because I need to send them to a server later on.
When the images are being converted the **memory rises a lot** and I have no idea how to fix this issue. also is it normal that when you show images in a collection-view it rises the memory from 30MB to like a 100MB just to show 10 images?

```
func elcImagePickerController(picker: ELCImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [AnyObject]!) {
    if (info.count == 0) {
        return
    }


    var pickedImages = NSMutableArray()
    var newImage = [UIImage()]
    for any in info {
            let dict = any as! NSMutableDictionary
            let image = dict.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as! UIImage
            newImage.append(image)
            pickedImages.addObject(image)



            println("Saving the image as binary data")
            println(" ")

            databaseHelper().createImage(image)
            // look at the button for the createImage func 


        }
    println("Adding selected images to image view", info.count)
    self.pickerImages = newImage
    self.pickerImages.removeAtIndex(0)
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    println(" ")
}
func createImage(image: UIImage) {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Settings")
    if let fetchResults = self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [Settings] {
        let newImage = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Image", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Image
        let convertImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, CGFloat(fetchResults[0].imageQuality))
        newImage.setValue(convertImage, forKey: "pickedImage")
    }
}
```

Comment: None knows how I can improve this? :(

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of strange stuff in your code. A fetch request to get one value from a Settings object? Why not use `NSUserDefaults`.

It seems you are making too many copies of your images in memory. For any given image, `pickedImages` contains a copy, `newImage` contains a copy and of course the cell displaying it contains another one.

Also, larger images should not be stored directly in Core Data as this degrades performance. You should store the images externally (e.g in the documents directory) and just store a string that lets you easily reconstruct the file path.

In the collection view's `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` you can create the image to be displayed *ad hoc* in with `UIImage.imageWithContentsOfFile()`.